Create .exe from .msi file
Is there a way to create a .exe installer from a .msi I did not create?
They should have the same information and behavior.
I already tried using AdvancedInstaller and the method posted here: convert msi to exe with a command line option...

that would loose all signing information. why do you want to do that in the first place?

This is a demand from my customer, his software must be a .exe
Losing all signing information is not a problem on this situation. If you know how to do that, it would help me a lot.
